# How can I check if a line contains specific string from a list of strings?

Tags: c#

I have a string, and a list of strings called `name`. I'm trying to check if a line of my list of string contains a name in the list.

My string:

```
peter has
julia has
elvis has
carol has
```

Lines of this string:

```
string[] lines = mystring.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

My list of strings contains : peter and elvis.

So it would show:

```
peter checked
elvis checked
```

I tried:

```
    for(int i =0;i < lines.Lenght;i++){
     for(int x =0; x < mylist.Count;x++){
       if(lines[i].Contains(mylist[x]){
         textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + mylist[x] + " checked";
       }
     }
   }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: Sorry, The error is that it is just showing the firt name and not all the names.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not your textbox. Maybe it isn't big enough to show all the text in it?  I run your code in a console window and change textbox1 to Console.WriteLine and get both results.

Comment: Yes, Im sure. If I make a loop for just show the lines , without the condition "contains". It shows right.

Comment: Does your list that contains peter and elvis have space padding before or after the words which makes the contains statement fail?

Comment: Yes, Im sure that does not contains spaces.

Comment: Ohh nooo, You are right.That was spaces in my list. Sorry man, and Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code doesn't look beautiful but at least works for me...

```
string[] line = { "peter has", "julia has", "elvis has", "carol has" };
string[] mylist = {"peter", "elvis"};
List<string> newitems = new List<string>();
string checkeditem;
foreach (var item in line)
{
    foreach (var check in mylist)
    {
        if (item.Contains(check))
        {
            checkeditem = item.Replace("has", "checked");
            newitems.Add(checkeditem);

        }
    }

}
//You can bind the newitems with your textbox1 here
```

Answer (score 2):

To return just the strings in a list which contain a substring from another list (names), do something like this:

```
var result = lines.Where(line => names.Any(name => line.Contains(name)));
```

Comment: It does not return the name that contains. Is there any way that I can use my example? I jsut need to know how can I correct my example. But thank you anyway.